# SageMaker Tensorflow - how to write my serving_input_fn()

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm pretty new to Tensorflow and SageMaker and I'm trying to figure out how to write my `serving_input_fn()`. I've tried a number of ways to do it, but to no avail.

my input function has 3 feature columns: `amount_normalized, x_month and y_month`:

```
def construct_feature_columns():
    amount_normalized = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='amount_normalized')
    x_month = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x_month')
    y_month = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='y_month')
    return set([amount_normalized, x_month, y_month])
```

I want to be able to call my deployed model using something like `deployed_model.predict([1.23,0.3,0.8])`

Where the first element is `amount_normalized`, second is `x_month` third is `y_month`

I've tried this:

```
FEATURES = ['amount_normalized', 'x_month', 'y_month']
def serving_input_fn(params):
    feature_placeholders = {
      key : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]) \
        for key in FEATURES
    }
return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_placeholders)()
```

But all I get is:
`An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "".`

Any help would be **really** appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this here in case anyone else has this issue.

After a bunch of trial and error I managed to solve my issue by writing my serving input function like this:

```
FEATURES = ['amount_normalized', 'x_month', 'y_month']
def serving_input_fn(hyperparameters):
    feature_spec = {
        key : tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype = tf.float32) \
          for key in FEATURES
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)()
```

I can then call my deployed model by passing in a hash:

```
deployed_model.predict({"amount_normalized": 2.3, "x_month": 0.2, "y_month": -0.3})
```